# How to remove an item from HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

I have some Javascript code to remove an item from a HTMLCollection as in code below. I get an error when splice is called that says: `allInputs.splice is not a function`. I need to remove items from HTMLCollection if the element type is not of button type.

**Question** : How would I remove an item from such a collection?

I could transfer undeleted items to an array and then I could work with the array instead of original HTMLCollection but not sure if there is any other shorter way of doing this.

**JavaScript code**

```
    var allInputs = contentElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = (allInputs.length - 1) ; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (allInputs[i].type !== "button") {
            allInputs.splice(i, 1);//this is throwing an error since splice is not defined
        }
    }
```

Comment: That first semi-colon in the for loop seems kinda out of place...

Comment: @bjskistad Looks right to me.

Comment: @bjskistad, I am looping backwards since I want to remove items from the collection.

Comment: A native HTMLCollection is not an array, it doesn't have a `splice` method, and elements can't be removed or added unless you actually remove or add them to the DOM. You probably want to convert it to an array.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm not the biggest fan of JavaScript. Probably works, I code in Python, so spaces matter a lot to me, probably doesn't matter in JS.

Comment: Convert the collection to an array if you want to use Array methods, such as `splice ()`; use `array.from(allInputs)` for example.

Comment: @Sunil I'm just talking about the space before the semi-colon, I'm just wondering if that is grammatically correct.

Comment: @bjskistad - doesn't matter, spaces generally mean nothing.

Comment: @bjskistad: yes, that white-space is fine.

Comment: @adeneo Ok, as I mentioned, I'm not the biggest JS guy. :P

Comment: @bjskistad, As already mentioned space will not matter in this case.

Comment: For full browser support -> `[].slice.call(allInputs)`

Comment: *"but not sure if there is any other shorter way of doing this."* There isn't.

Comment: @adeneo, Is `[]` in `[].slice.call(allInputs)` the HTMLCollection?

Comment: @Sunil - no, it's `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HTMLCollection` is a live array-like object, that means if you need to remove an element from such collection, you will have to remove it from the DOM. You can always clone it into an Array for manipulations.

Answer (score 17):

You need to remove it from the DOM, so replace:

```
allInputs.splice(i, 1);
```

with:

```
allInputs[i].parentNode.removeChild(allInputs[i])
```

which is compatible wilth even ancient browsers like IE 6. The collection will update automatically. Iterating over the collection in reverse is a good idea as each time you remove a member, it will get shorter.

Note that:

```
[].slice.call(allInputs)
```

will fail in browsers like IE8 that do not allow host objects to be *this* in built–in methods.

Answer (score 4):

To remove an newly created **img** from HTMLCollection **images** I'd uset next string

```
img.ownerDocument.images[img.index].remove()
```

where ***img.index*** was defined on creation

Answer (score 4):

It is actually possible to do this, you just need to push the elements you want into another HTMLCollection, then set the original collection to the new collection (or just use the new collection)

```
var allInputs = contentElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
var inputsWeActuallyWant = [];
for (var i = (allInputs.length - 1) ; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allInputs[i].type === "button") {
        inputsWeActuallyWant.push(allInputs[i]);
    }
}
allInputs = inputsWeActuallyWant;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Array.splice`. However, the `length` property of `HTMLCollection`s is read-only, so in order to use an Array method like splice, you have to explicitly make it writable beforehand:

```
Object.defineProperty(allInputs, 'length', {
  writable: true
})
Array.prototype.splice.call(allInputs, i, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 var allInputs = contentElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
 let newArr = []
 let i = 0;
 while(i<allInputs.length){
       //Add Your Filter Here
        if (allInputs[i].type !== "button") {
              //skip this Item
              i++;
        }else{
             //add it
             newArr.push(allInputs[i])
             //code..
             i++;
        }
 }
```

Your New List is `newArr` :)

after that you can use `newArr.forEach(function(el){//code here})`.